# Are import/export scripts backward compatible?

Tags: scripting, export, import

I want to install an export script into blender 2.79. The last version of the script ([iqm_export](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/blender-2.74/iqm_export.py)) is for blender 2.74.

Will this script still work in blender 2.79, and if so, are all blender scripts backwards compatible?

Comment: No, not all of the functionality is compatible, since the module `Blender` got replaced by `bpy` for example. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @leander your thinking of 2.49, since 2.74 not a lot has changed. For a simple scene the addon seems to work.

Comment: @eeze - Note that if you enable export armature you need to have an armature selected. If you do have issues exporting, have a look at [the dazkind fork](https://github.com/dazKind/iqm), it has recent activity including a 2.8-alpha addon, they may also respond to issues reported on github.